# How to test a function that make AWSMobileClient request in swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, testing

I have a function

```swift
final class API {
  func forgotPassword(
    username: String
  ) -> Future<ConfirmationStatus, Never> {
    Future { _ in
      AWSMobileClient.default().forgotPassword(
        username: username
      ) { forgotPasswordResult, error in
        if let forgotPasswordResult = forgotPasswordResult {
          switch forgotPasswordResult.forgotPasswordState {
          case .confirmationCodeSent:
            // show an alert to a user here
            break
          default:
            logger.error("Error: Invalid case.")
          }
        } else if let error = error {
          logger.error("Error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
      }
    }.onFailure {
      logger.error($0)
    }
  }
}
```

that will be called when a user tap on a button. I want to test it. I understand in general how should I test it. I should create a function that will be called instead of `AWSMobileClient.default().forgotPassword()` and it I should use it in `forgotPassword` test.
It might be function in a extension on a protocol. And `AWSMobileClient` should conform to this protocol.

How should I test `API.forgotPassword`?

I used [BrightFuture](https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures) to make asynchronous requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be protocol that allows dependency injection.

Let it be `AuthClient`. It should have all properties that we will use from `AWSMobileClient`.  And declare an extension.

```swift
extension AWSMobileClient: AuthClient {}
```

We should have a class that will conform to this protocol. For example `Auth`. It should have an `authClient` property. It will be variable that care our auth client.

Somewhere on the top of the app we will have `Auth` initialisation that takes `ASWMobileClient` as a `authClient`

```swift
Auth(AWSMobileClient.default())
```

In the tests we should pass a mock to `Auth`. `MockAuthClient: AuthClient` will have all methods that we want to test and use in our app.